# Who is serial downvoting me on my Politics.SE birthday?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

Someone (or two someones?) just downvoted all my Politics.SE answers around the same time as I earned the Yearling badge. Does the system do this or is this someone pursuing a vendetta against me? And if it is a vendetta, can I report it to have anything done about it? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For serial (down)voting patterns like that the system will automatically undo it after a day or two.

In the meantime, I'll see If there's anything I can do to investigate this, and see if there's any Stack Exchange standard remedy for this kind of behavior.

Comment: The serial voting reversal script runs every night at 3 AM (UTC time).

Comment: The system overturned the serial downvoting. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JDoe In this case, I did contact support about it 3 days ago because the automatic script hadn't seemed to have corrected it for 4 days