# Someone is stalking my profile, how do I report it?

Tags: support, voting

Someone is stalking my profile and serial upvoting my old posts. How do I report it?

Comment: Stalking your profile?

Comment: @JoeW yes. Serial upvoting of 3 questions which are tagged different and not being pinged by the community user means stalking.

Comment: How does 3 questions getting upvotes mean you are being stalked?

Comment: Three (now four) upvotes within 5-6 minutes. @JJJ. How could it mean anything different?

Comment: Several different people saw your questions and upvoted?

Comment: If someone is serial voting on your posts the system has a script that runs daily that will fix it.

Comment: @JoeW probable but unlikely.

Comment: Mostly this happens when people have a grudge against someone and start to downvote a number of their posts. There's a script that looks at serial voting and it may overturn such patterns based on parameters that I don't know specifically. See also the answer at [Who is serial downvoting me on my Politics.SE birthday?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2832). Of course it may also be a coincidence if different people happen to stumble upon some of your posts at the same time.

Comment: @JoeW thanks that answers my question.

Comment: @JJJ this is about serial upvoting though. I see number of reasons why someone may do so

Comment: The script doesn't care which way the votes are, it just looks for serial voting and corrects it. Serial upvoting is actually worse for the system than serial downvoting

Comment: @JoeW yes, it is worse. Why according to you?

Comment: Because everything on stack exchange runs based on on your reputation and serial upvoting increases your reputation. If you get a large reputation increase from serial upvoting you will have privileges and access that you did not earn and do not deserve and they can be used to harm the site.

Comment: Honestly most people won't complain about gaining rep which is why you don't see threads asking about serial upvotes.

Comment: @JoeW So I am being extra-cuatious. I don't vote. I don't close vote. I understand I am not as eligible. I am a responsible person. I agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to report, because the person "stalking" your profile didn't do anything worth reporting.

Your Stack Exchange profile is public information. People are allowed to look at it as much as they want. And if they choose to go through some of your older posts, find them useful and upvote them, that's their right.

What's forbidden on Stack Exchange is systematically upvoting or downvoting all posts of a user without even reading the content. The motive behind that is usually to artificially inflate or deflate the reputation of an account, which is detrimental to the Stack Exchange system.

But with just 3 upvotes in a day we can hardly call that serial upvoting. Also, the votes I believe you are talking about were several minutes apart, so it doesn't look like they voted without reading. ([this is all public information, by the way](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/34768/gary-2?tab=reputation))

However, should you do become the victim of actual serial voting in the future, you can report that by flagging any of your own posts as "in need of moderator intervention" and explain the situation in the free text field.

Comment: *Also, the votes I believe you are talking about were several minutes apart* [those weren't](https://postimg.cc/LYdYXq0H). If it was one person they voted without reading. I just wanted to report, because some of the moderators (not you) might blame me. I had been a victim of cynicism.

Comment: I was cautious, you know? I appreciate your answer here. I want to thank you for responding.

Comment: @Gary2 Those are not even 3 upvotes. That's one actual upvote and one upvote which was undone immediately.

Comment: You are right, the one I was talking about earlier were [several minutes apart](https://postimg.cc/zbBg4mMh). Anyways, I thought something was fishy. Sincerely, I didn't notice and didn't know that it was possible to see the time. Thanks Philipp.